# php check if variable exists in url and and replace value

Tags: php

I wrote a function that allows me to do pagination. here's the problem: when I click on the button to change the page to the url, many same values are added, as in the following case:

newsletter.php?action=sent-emails&page=2&page=1&page=4&page=5&page=7&page=5&page=1

```
function pagination($sql_general,$page_name_pagination,$page_query_pagination) {
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'it/intranet/includes/dbh.inc.php';
  $sql1 =  $sql_general;
  $sql1_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
  $total = mysqli_num_rows($sql1_query);
  $adjacents = 3;
  $targetpage = $page_name_pagination; //your file name


  if (!empty($page_query_pagination)) {
    $targetpage .= "?" . $page_query_pagination . "&page=";

  } else {
    $targetpage .= "?page=";
  }

  $limit = 10; //how many items to show per page
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  if($page){
  $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; //first item to display on this page
  }else{
  $start = 0;
  }

  /* Setup page vars for display. */
  if ($page == 0) $page = 1; //if no page var is given, default to 1.
  $prev = $page - 1; //previous page is current page - 1
  $next = $page + 1; //next page is current page + 1
  $lastpage = ceil($total/$limit); //lastpage.
  $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1; //last page minus 1

  $pagination = "";
  if($lastpage > 1)
  {
  $pagination .= "<div class='pagination1'> <ul class='pagination'>";
  if ($page > $counter+1) {
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$prev\"><</a></li>";
  }

  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
  {
  for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
  {
  if ($counter == $page)
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' >$counter</a></li>";
  else
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$counter\">$counter</a></li>";
  }
  }
  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
  {
  //close to beginning; only hide later pages
  if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
  {
  for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
  {
  if ($counter == $page)
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' >$counter</a></li>";
  else
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$counter\">$counter</a></li>";
  }
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'>...</li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>";
  }
  //in middle; hide some front and some back
  elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
  {
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage1\">1</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage2\">2</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'>...</li>";
  for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
  {
  if ($counter == $page)
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' >$counter</a></li>";
  else
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$counter\">$counter</a></li>";
  }
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'>...</li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$lpm1\">$lpm1</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$lastpage\">$lastpage</a></li>";
  }
  //close to end; only hide early pages
  else
  {
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage1\">1</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage2\">2</a></li>";
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'>...</li>";
  for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage;
  $counter++)
  {
  if ($counter == $page)
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' >$counter</a></li>";
  else
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$counter\">$counter</a></li>";
  }
  }
  }

  //next button
  if ($page < $counter - 1)
  $pagination.= "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href=\"$targetpage$next\">></a></li>";
  else
  $pagination.= "";
  $pagination.= "</ul></div>\n";
  }

echo "$pagination";

}
```

Now, how can i  check if "page=x" exists and replace the value?

Comment: Indenting code may seem like waste of spaces but it isn't... And also not sure what the issue really is. Is it the duplicated entries in the link or is it all the HTML you generate with the code? I feel like the question, text and code are not really connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split, modify/add and compose:

```
parse_str($query_string,$list);
if (isset($list['name'])
{
     // name= exists, modify it
}
else
{
     // name= not exists
     $list['name'] = "new value";
}
$query_string = http_build_query($list);
```